# Which systemd service this port use?

Tags: systemd, port

I have installed a program that uses systemd

```
sudo netstat -lntp | grep 10700           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10700         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2444/systemd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:10700               :::*                    LISTEN      2444/systemd
```

the process is named systemd

```
ps aux | grep 2444                                                                                                                                                            
asd         2444  0.0  0.0  20124 10836 ?        Ss   Jan28   0:04 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
```

What command to check the process or at least the systemd service name that uses that port?

note: the program I'm installing is edgedb

```
edgedb instance list
┌───────┬──────┬───────┬─────────────┬────────┐
│ Kind  │ Name │ Port  │ Version     │ Status │
├───────┼──────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────┤
│ local │ foo  │ 10700 │ 2.9+b1d697b │ ready  │
└───────┴──────┴───────┴─────────────┴────────┘
```

I just need to know what process being spawned (since `sudo ps aux | grep edge` (or foo, or postgres) doesn't show anything)

**UPDATE**: ah apparently it was postgres, that only spawned if `edgedb` client command running:

```
ps aux | grep postgres
asd       912323  0.0  0.0 372924 107732 ?       SN   04:15   0:00 /home/asd/.local/share/edgedb/portable/2.9/bin/postgres -D /home/asd/.local/share/edgedb/data/foo -c listen_addresses= -c unix_socket_permissions=0700 -c unix_socket_directories=/run/user/1000/edgedb-foo -c max_connections=1289 -c max_locks_per_transaction=256 -c log_min_messages=NOTICE -c log_statement=none -c log_line_prefix=
asd       912325  0.0  0.0 372924  3548 ?        SNs  04:15   0:00 postgres: checkpointer
asd       912326  0.0  0.0 373260  9664 ?        SNs  04:15   0:00 postgres: background writer
asd       912327  0.0  0.0 372924  8944 ?        SNs  04:15   0:00 postgres: walwriter
asd       912328  0.0  0.0 374508  7844 ?        SNs  04:15   0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher
asd       912329  0.0  0.0  71644  4944 ?        SNs  04:15   0:00 postgres: stats collector
asd       912330  0.0  0.0 374232  5992 ?        SNs  04:15   0:00 postgres: logical replication launcher
asd       912335  0.0  0.0 386380 44756 ?        SNs  04:15   0:00 postgres: postgres V2f147ded60___edgedbsys__ [local] idle
asd       912337  0.0  0.0 401464 66444 ?        SNs  04:15   0:00 postgres: postgres V2f147ded60_edgedb [local] idle

edgedb instance list
┌───────┬──────┬───────┬─────────────┬─────────┐
│ Kind  │ Name │ Port  │ Version     │ Status  │
├───────┼──────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────┤
│ local │ foo  │ 10700 │ 2.9+b1d697b │ running │
└───────┴──────┴───────┴─────────────┴─────────┘
```

but the question still stands for the future, how to know which systemd file that use that port?

Comment: Kokizzu, `lsof -i :10700` gives information which process(es) use(s) this port, but I don't believe you will get more info than with `-p` option of `netstat`. `lsof` requires `root` priviledges.